# How to implement Jquery datetime picker with slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have spent literally 2 days trying to get the Jquery datepicker with the time slider on my web page working without any success. The datepicker has just never appeared on the page regardless of what I do:

On my web page I have the following:

```
<link href="/Content/bootstrap/css/jquery/timepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Content/bootstrap/css/jquery/jquery.ui.datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-lib/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-lib/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript"  src="/Content/bootstrap/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/Content/bootstrap/js/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"  src="/Content/bootstrap/js/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>
```

And script:

```
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#datetimepicker").datepicker();
        });
</script>
```

I have also tried:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#datetimepicker").datetimepicker();
    });
```

And in the body I tried:

```
<div id="datetimepicker" class="ui-datepicker"></div>
```

And

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" class="ui-datepicker" id="datetimepicker"></p>

<div><input id="datetimepicker" class="ui-datepicker" type="text" value="" name="basic_example_1"/></div>
```

Can someone send please help me by showing an example of jquery datetimepicker with slider working in jsfiddle?

Or tell me exactly how to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

**HTML CODE:**

```
<p>Date:</p>
    <div>
    <input type="text" name="datetimepicker" id="datetimepicker" value="" />
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
```

<kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/B9hP3/2/)**</kbd>

**NOTE:** Make sure that jQuery-2.0.3.js, jQuery-UI.js and resources that are added in enternal resources in fiddle are included in your code.

Comment: This is good. A date calender pops up but it looks totally different from the on in jsfiddle

Comment: change the views according to your requirement. This is just a sample.

Comment: What css are you actually using in jsfiddle?

Comment: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css. check external resources for js code links.

Comment: No slider on calender

Comment: time slider is there.